# Trying to implement ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd in a 3.5 project

Tags: c#, concurrency, .net-3.5

In a .Net 4.5 project, I use a simple utility method to memoize results in a **thread safe** way (a web app actually):

```
public static class FuncUtilities
{
    public static Func<TArg, TResult> ThreadsafeMemoize<TArg, TResult>(Func<TArg, TResult> f)
    {
        var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<TArg, TResult>();

        return arg => cache.GetOrAdd(arg, f);
    }

    public static Func<TArg, TArg2, TResult> ThreadsafeMemoize<TArg, TArg2, TResult>(Func<TArg, TArg2, TResult> f)
    {
        var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<TArg, TArg2>, TResult>();
        return (arg, arg2) =>
        {
            var key = new Tuple<TArg, TArg2>(arg, arg2);
            return cache.GetOrAdd(key, f(arg, arg2));
        };
    }

    public static Func<TArg, TArg2, TArg3, TResult> ThreadsafeMemoize<TArg, TArg2, TArg3, TResult>(Func<TArg, TArg2, TArg3, TResult> f)
    {
        var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<TArg, TArg2, TArg3>, TResult>();
        return (arg, arg2, arg3) =>
        {
            var key = new Tuple<TArg, TArg2, TArg3>(arg, arg2, arg3);
            return cache.GetOrAdd(key, f(arg, arg2, arg3));
        };
    }
}
```

In a another project, wich must run with 3.5, I have the same requirement of memoizing the results.

How to port my code to .Net 3.5?

I [found partial port of the class](http://www.grumpydev.com/2010/02/25/thread-safe-dictionarytkeytvalue/), but it lacks the `GetOrAdd`  method, so I tried to implement it myself:

```
public class ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly object _Padlock = new object();

    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { lock (_Padlock) { return _Dictionary[key]; } }
        set { lock (_Padlock) { _Dictionary[key] = value; } }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        lock (_Padlock)
        {
            return _Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
    }

    public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> factory)
    {
        lock (_Padlock)
        {
            if (!_Dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _Dictionary.Add(key, factory(key));
            }
            return _Dictionary[key];
        }
    }
}
```

I also have to "simulate" the `Tuple` class by nesting `KeyValuePair`

```
public static class FuncUtilities
{
    public static Func<TArg, TResult> ThreadsafeMemoize<TArg, TResult>(Func<TArg, TResult> f)
    {
        var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<TArg, TResult>();

        return arg => cache.GetOrAdd(arg, f);
    }

    public static Func<TArg, TArg2, TResult> ThreadsafeMemoize<TArg, TArg2, TResult>(Func<TArg, TArg2, TResult> f)
    {
        var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<KeyValuePair<TArg, TArg2>, TResult>();
        return (arg, arg2) =>
        {
            var key = new KeyValuePair<TArg, TArg2>(arg, arg2);
            return cache.GetOrAdd(key, f(arg, arg2));
        };
    }

    public static Func<TArg, TArg2, TArg3, TResult> ThreadsafeMemoize<TArg, TArg2, TArg3, TResult>(Func<TArg, TArg2, TArg3, TResult> f)
    {
        var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<TArg, TArg2>, TArg3>, TResult>();
        return (arg, arg2, arg3) =>
        {
            var key = new KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<TArg, TArg2>, TArg3>(new KeyValuePair<TArg, TArg2>(arg, arg2), arg3);
            return cache.GetOrAdd(key, f(arg, arg2, arg3));
        };
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not compiles:

> 1>C:\some\FuncUtilities.cs(29,24,29,57):
>   error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'some.ConcurrentDictionary,TResult>.GetOrAdd(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair,
>   System.Func,TResult>)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>   1>C:\some\FuncUtilities.cs(29,44,29,56):
>   error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'TResult' to
>   'System.Func,TResult>'
>   1>C:\some\FuncUtilities.cs(39,24,39,63):
>   error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'some.ConcurrentDictionary,TArg3>,TResult>.GetOrAdd(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair,TArg3>,
>   System.Func,TArg3>,TResult>)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>   1>C:\some\FuncUtilities.cs(39,44,39,62):
>   error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'TResult' to
>   'System.Func,TArg3>,TResult>'

Comment: You can use this [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary) which contains `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: actually, adding new dependencies is not an option. The whole picture is a bit more complicated

Comment: Then refer .net framework source and copy the implementation. IANAL, so better check the license agreement for details on this is permitted or not.

Comment: Rereading my code, I start to believe than the Tuple'd version of the methods are incorrect also in the original 4.5 version

Comment: I wish people would try this approach and use GetOrAdd, instead of creating ICache and then using ConcurrentDictionary like it was a normal Dictionary.